# Facing Table of contents problem?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

On first page of Table of Contents there is no header and footer, but on the second page there are a header and a footer.

My question: I don't need any numbering and header/footer on table of content. How can I have the entire table of contents (not only its first page) appear with no header or footer, and have them start at Chapter 1?

```
\documentclass[tikz,table,twoside,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{PTSansNarrow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{censor}
\censorruledepth=-.2ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}
\textwidth14cm
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.3,0.5}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment%
{MyVerbatim}{Verbatim}
{gobble=0,label=\hspace{.85\textwidth},labelposition=all}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}%Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjornstrup and Bjarne
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
% load package with ``framed'' and ``numbered'' option.
\usepackage[numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\clearpage
\title{\textbf{THESIS NAME}\\
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo.eps}
\end{figure}
}

\date{}
\author{\textbf{SUBMITTED BY:}\\\textbf{STUDENT NAME}
\vspace{5mm}
\\
\textbf{Supervised By}\\
\textbf{NAME}\quad
\vspace{10mm}
\\
\textbf{DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE} \\\textbf{NAME OF UNIVERSITY}        \\\textbf{Session:2012-2013} }
\maketitle

\null
\vfill
\null
\vfill
\onehalfspacing
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter* {PROJECT APPROVAL}
SAKASLJFSAJFKSAJFJEIJ S\KJ\\\\
\newline
COMMITTEE\\\\
\newline
\begin{flushleft}
External Examiner: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
Comments: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
Internal Examiner: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
 Comments: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
 Chairman: \line(1,0){250}
 \end{flushleft}
 \begin{flushleft}
 Comments: \line(1,0){250}
 \end{flushleft}

\chapter* {DEDICATION}
 KSAHDSAFH ASK JFASKJF

\chapter* {ABSTRACT}
 XCLSCSAJFSAFOSAFISADKFLASKFL;ASKSAKFLKSALKFS

\chapter* {ACKNOWLEDGEMENT}
LSAFLDSFJ SDAFJIASFAS JFSJAF SFSFAUI DSAF
\chapter* {AUTHOR'S DECLARATION}
ABC
\newline
Signature of Authors\\
\newline
ABC: \xblackout{forty       two}\\
\newline
ABC: \xblackout{forty     two}\\
\newline
Date: \xblackout{forty     two}\\



\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{ch1}
\input{ch2}
\input{ch3}
\input{ch4}
\input{ch5}
\input{ch6}
\input{ch7}
\input{ch8}


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Bibliography}}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibk}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is done on purpose. `tableofcontents` uses a `\clearpage` and `\thispagestyle{empty}`, so no headers/footers and page numbers are shown

Comment: Please post a MWE also, your document is by far not a **minimal** WE... and it is **not working** too `;-)`, so its just an **E**...

Comment: @Christian Hupfer MWE stand for?

Comment: MWE = minimally working example, see [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) please

Comment: I think both of u are not interested to solve my problem

Comment: @LaTeXKhan: Pardon me, but I was confused about this unclear question. And pardon me again, but it was rather you that was uninterested to provide a MWE at all, although I asked you about it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Just check the image which provide above with  code, then u will understand my problem.

Comment: @LaTeXKhan: I have updated the solution already about 15min ago `;-)`

Comment: @LaTeXKhan While an image is always useful to help understanding what the question is about, it cannot replace a clearly formulated question, written in proper english. If Christian had no interest, he wouldn't have answered. And if I had no interest, I wouldn't have editted the question to save it from being closed. I agree though that our messages are not really constructive and should be deleted now.

Comment: @LateXKhan: Alright ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I do not know whether this output is intended, but I `\relaxed` basically the `\thispagestyle{}` command within a `\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}`, so that actually headers etc. are applied.

**Edit: The first version of this question was quite unclear or even contradicting, so I used this answer, but I will not update it.**

The important lines are

```
\let\LaTeXStandardTOC\tableofcontents%
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\thispagestyle}[1]{%
\relax% Do nothing at all
}%
\LaTeXStandardTOC%
\endgroup
}%
```

The `renewcommand{\thispagestyle}` to do nothing must be `grouped`, so that it is effective only there and works as expected when other calls to  that command occur.

---

```
\documentclass[tikz,table,twoside,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{PTSansNarrow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{censor}
\censorruledepth=-.2ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}
\textwidth14cm
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.3,0.5}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment%
{MyVerbatim}{Verbatim}
{gobble=0,label=\hspace{.85\textwidth},labelposition=all}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}%Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjornstrup and Bjarne
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
% load package with ``framed'' and ``numbered'' option.
%\usepackage[numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\clearpage
\title{\textbf{THESIS NAME}\\
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo.eps}
\end{figure}
}

\date{}
\author{\textbf{SUBMITTED BY:}\\\textbf{STUDENT NAME}
\vspace{5mm}
\\
\textbf{Supervised By}\\
\textbf{NAME}\quad
\vspace{10mm}
\\
\textbf{DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE} \\\textbf{NAME OF UNIVERSITY}        \\\textbf{Session:2012-2013} }
\maketitle

\null
\vfill
\null
\vfill
\onehalfspacing
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter* {PROJECT APPROVAL}
%SAKASLJFSAJFKSAJFJEIJ S\KJ\\\\
%\newline
COMMITTEE\\ % \\
\newline
\begin{flushleft}
External Examiner: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
Comments: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
Internal Examiner: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
 Comments: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
 Chairman: \line(1,0){250}
 \end{flushleft}
 \begin{flushleft}
 Comments: \line(1,0){250}
 \end{flushleft}

\chapter* {DEDICATION}
 KSAHDSAFH ASK JFASKJF

\chapter* {ABSTRACT}
 XCLSCSAJFSAFOSAFISADKFLASKFL;ASKSAKFLKSALKFS

\chapter* {ACKNOWLEDGEMENT}
LSAFLDSFJ SDAFJIASFAS JFSJAF SFSFAUI DSAF
\chapter* {AUTHOR'S DECLARATION}
ABC
\newline
Signature of Authors\\
\newline
ABC: \xblackout{forty       two}\\
\newline
ABC: \xblackout{forty     two}\\
\newline
Date: \xblackout{forty     two}\\

\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Number 1}
\blindtext
\chapter{Number 2}
\section{1}
\section{2}
\section{3}
\section{4}
\section{5}
\section{6}
\section{7}
\section{8}
\section{9}

\blindtext

\chapter{Number 3}
\blindtext

\chapter{Number 4}
\blindtext

\chapter{Number 5}
\blindtext

\chapter{Number 6}
\blindtext

\chapter{Number 7}
\section{1}
\section{2}
\section{3}

\blindtext

\chapter{Number 8}
\blindtext


%\input{ch1}
%\input{ch2}
%\input{ch3}
%\input{ch4}
%\input{ch5}
%\input{ch6}
%\input{ch7}
%\input{ch8}


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Bibliography}}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibk}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note** I had to comment some lines to make the example compile!

**Edit** Solution without header and footer for TOC
If `\pagestyle{fancy}` is active while `\tablecontents` is to be shipped out, there is no wonder that this will hold for the second and following pages of the TOC too. So shift the `\pagestyle` to a place afterwards, apply a `\clearpage` before.

```
\documentclass[tikz,table,twoside,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{PTSansNarrow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{censor}
\censorruledepth=-.2ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}
\textwidth14cm
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.3,0.5}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment%
{MyVerbatim}{Verbatim}
{gobble=0,label=\hspace{.85\textwidth},labelposition=all}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}%Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjornstrup and Bjarne
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
% load package with ``framed'' and ``numbered'' option.
%\usepackage[numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\clearpage
\title{\textbf{THESIS NAME}\\
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo.eps}
\end{figure}
}

\date{}
\author{\textbf{SUBMITTED BY:}\\\textbf{STUDENT NAME}
\vspace{5mm}
\\
\textbf{Supervised By}\\
\textbf{NAME}\quad
\vspace{10mm}
\\
\textbf{DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE} \\\textbf{NAME OF UNIVERSITY}        \\\textbf{Session:2012-2013} }
\maketitle

\null
\vfill
\null
\vfill
\onehalfspacing
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter* {PROJECT APPROVAL}
%SAKASLJFSAJFKSAJFJEIJ S\KJ\\\\
%\newline
COMMITTEE\\ % \\
\newline
\begin{flushleft}
External Examiner: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
Comments: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
Internal Examiner: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
 Comments: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
 Chairman: \line(1,0){250}
 \end{flushleft}
 \begin{flushleft}
 Comments: \line(1,0){250}
 \end{flushleft}

\chapter* {DEDICATION}
 KSAHDSAFH ASK JFASKJF

\chapter* {ABSTRACT}
 XCLSCSAJFSAFOSAFISADKFLASKFL;ASKSAKFLKSALKFS

\chapter* {ACKNOWLEDGEMENT}
LSAFLDSFJ SDAFJIASFAS JFSJAF SFSFAUI DSAF
\chapter* {AUTHOR'S DECLARATION}
ABC
\newline
Signature of Authors\\
\newline
ABC: \xblackout{forty       two}\\
\newline
ABC: \xblackout{forty     two}\\
\newline
Date: \xblackout{forty     two}\\


\let\LaTeXStandardTOC\tableofcontents%
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\thispagestyle}[1]{%
\relax% Do nothing at all
}%
\LaTeXStandardTOC%
\endgroup
}%

\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\clearpage%
\pagestyle{fancy}


\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Number 1}
\blindtext
\chapter{Number 2}
\section{1}
\section{2}
\section{3}
\section{4}
\section{5}
\section{6}
\section{7}
\section{8}
\section{9}

\blindtext

\chapter{Number 3}
\blindtext

\chapter{Number 4}
\blindtext

\chapter{Number 5}
\blindtext

\chapter{Number 6}
\blindtext

\chapter{Number 7}
\section{1}
\section{2}
\section{3}

\blindtext

\chapter{Number 8}
\blindtext


%\input{ch1}
%\input{ch2}
%\input{ch3}
%\input{ch4}
%\input{ch5}
%\input{ch6}
%\input{ch7}
%\input{ch8}


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Bibliography}}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibk}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't need header n footer as well as also numbering on Table of content.

Comment: @LaTeXKhan: So, what was your question then?

Comment: my Question is that I don't need any numbering and header footer on table of content. Just simply show me Table of Content and from Chapter 1 is start the numbering with header n footer.

Comment: @LaTeXKhan: That is not stated in your question ;-)