# table of contents modification with fancyhdr

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr

I am using the fancyhdr package in the article document class.  I would like all pages (including the table of contents page) to have the header and footer that I prescribe in the preamble.

I would also like to modify the table of contents name with the following command:

`\renewcommand\contentsname{\centering\bf TABLE OF CONTENTS}`

With this `\renewcommand` in the preamble, LaTeX stops at `\tableofcontents` (no error given).  I can either leave the `\renewcommand` in and change to plain pagestyle, or I can remove the command and use my fancy header and footer, but I cannot do both.

Does anyone know of a command that will remove/avoid the conflict between the `renewcommand` and the fancy pagestyle?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I think, `\centering` is the source of the error. `\bf` is outdated and should be avoided, use `\textbf{...}` instead. Besides, the `\contentsname` is printed in bold font usually

Comment: The next problem could be, that `\tableofcontent` uses a `\thispagestyle{plain}` (as far as I know), such that headers/footers are disregarded.

Comment: Please try the first code block (the one with `\let\LaTeXStandardToc\...`) I used in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185782/facing-table-of-contents-problem/185784#185784. This should prevent the empty or plain pagestyle of the TOC.

Comment: The first code block from the other answer did not solve the problem.  However, the problem is indeed caused by \centering, so I simply removed that and added spaces to center the revised table of contents name.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's a really bad way to do this. If you would add an MWE as mentioned above, somebody would be happy to help you find a better solution.

Comment: @Henry: The mentioned code block was not meant to cure the problem regarding the error message about the `centering`, it was meant to give you the possibility of having centered headings/footings by disabling the `\thispagestyle{plain}` inside the `\tableofcontents`.